# Confusing About OpenCL Driver and Software

Tags: opencl

I am new in OpenCL. I have an Dell XPS 1645 laptop which has ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4670 graphics card and a Intel CPU. I saw that AMD's software does not support OpenCL stuff for my graphics card but in Khronos website, my video card is seen as OpenCL supported. So, what do I have to do to start OpenCL programming? Also, can I use AMD's software which is for OpenCL?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a laptop with Windows 7, an Intel Core i7  CPU with 4 cores and hyper-threading?

Well OpenCL can run on CPU's as well as GPU's.  With this model won't be able to access the GPU as an OpenCL device, but you can still use  the CPU as an OpenCL device.

So download the OpenCL  SDK from Intel or AMD, or both. Install it and try the examples.

You will have the change the calls  to
clGetDeviceIds( ....  )

so that the device type specified is  always CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU